# Apache reverse proxy to https site gives (70014)End of file found:

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I'm using apache mod_proxy to reverse proxy to a backend HTTPS server that is working on a non-standard port (blocked by several firewalls hense the need for a reverse proxy).

The client connection is over HTTPS to apache, which then inturn connects to what I beleive is either an nginx or tomcat server (the backend server is a Zimbra mail servers administration console).

I'm getting the following error in the logs

```
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //[internal_url]:7071/
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1506): [client [client_ip] proxy: https: found worker https://[internal_url]:7071/ for https://[internal_url]:7071/
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] mod_proxy.c(968): Trying to run scheme_handler against proxy
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL https://[internal_url]:7071/
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1949): proxy: HTTPS: retrying the worker for ([internal_url])
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1955): proxy: HTTPS: worker for ([internal_url]) has been marked for retry
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2011): proxy: HTTPS: has acquired connection for ([internal_url])
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2067): proxy: connecting https://[internal_url]:7071/ to [internal_url]:7071
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2193): proxy: connected https://[internal_url]:7071/ to [internal_url]:7071
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTPS: fam 2 socket created to connect to [internal_url]
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2285): proxy: CONNECT: sending the CONNECT request for [internal_url]:7071 to the remote proxy [internal_ip]:7071 ([internal_url])
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [error] (70014)End of file found: proxy: HTTPS: attempt to connect to [internal_url]:7071 via http CONNECT through [internal_ip]:7071 ([internal_url]) failed
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for ([internal_url])
[Thu Jun 27 11:35:26 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2029): proxy: HTTPS: has released connection for ([internal_url])
```

with the following configuration on an Ubuntu 12.10 server with "apache2 2.2.22-6ubuntu2.2" and "libapache2-mod-proxy-html 3.0.1-1.1" packages installed

```
    ProxyRequests   on
    ProxyRemote     *       https://[internal_url]:7071
    ProxyPass       /       https://[internal_url]:7071/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       https://[internal_url]:7071/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain    [internal_url] [external_url]

    SSLProxyEngine  on

    ProxyPreserveHost       on
    ProxyVia        on
```

I have no idea what more I can do. The backend server site is accessible via lynx from the apache server so it's not a blantly obvious issue to me.

Comment: Your issue could be related to CA certificates. Try following Vortura answer on ServerFault to see if your certificates are valid: [see here](http://serverfault.com/questions/516696/apache-proxy-ssl-authentication-failure-on-back-end-of-proxy-client-side).You'd better ask this question on StackExchange where it is more relevant.

Comment: Can you snoop the TCP and look at the request from the client's end? That way you can at least find out wether the connection is being established, and if so, whether the server is returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right - your communication route looks like this

Browser  Apache  backend server

In this case, you must remove the ProxyRemote directive - because it's only needed if you communicate via another proxy with the backend server.

Comment: cyberflohr is correct (and both your error message AND the Apache documentation are not very helpful).  Remove `ProxyRequests` and `ProxyRemote` and everything should just work.